# I have .pem privatekey and .der encrypted file. I want to decrypt using nodejs

Tags: node.js, encryption, openssl

I have used the following commands to generate the encrypted file "Example.txt.der".

1. openssl genrsa -out privatekey.pem 2048
2. openssl req -new -sha256 -key privatekey.pem -out csr.csr
3. openssl req -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -key privatekey.pem -in csr.csr -out certificate.pem
4. openssl smime -encrypt -aes-256-cbc -binary -in Example.txt -outform DER -out Example.txt.der certificate.pem

I want to decrypt "Example.txt.der" using : privatekey.pem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command:

```
openssl smime -decrypt -in Example.txt.der -inform DER -inkey privatekey.pem -out DecryptedExample.txt
```

Comment: If the answer did help you, please upvote and accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It works using exec command.

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec; exec('openssl smime -decrypt -in ./encryptedConfig.txt -inkey ./privatekey.pem', (error, stdout, stderr) => { if (error) { console.log("error:",error); reject(error); } else { console.log("Config decrypt completed. Data: ",stdout); resolve(stdout); }
```